# Ruby on Rails: show page show something wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Here is my **show.html.erb**

```
<h1> <%= @category.name %> </h1>
<ul>
<%= @category.soups.each do |soup| %>
<li> 
    <%= link_to soup.name , soup %> 
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<p> <%= link_to "back", categories_path %></p>
```

However, here is the result. 
[image]

Why it shows

```
[#<Soup id: 1, name: "Tonkotsu", featured: true, category_id: 1, created_at: "2015-07-22 11:30:37", updated_at: "2015-07-22 16:59:20">, #<Soup id: 4, name: "Beef Flavor", featured: nil, category_id: 1, created_at: "2015-07-22 17:03:34", updated_at: "2015-07-22 17:10:36">]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
<%= @category.soups.each do |soup| %>
```

to

```
<% @category.soups.each do |soup| %>
```

- `<% %>` -----> Executes the statement.
- `<%= %>` ----> Prints the output.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Great help.

Answer (score 1):

you have "=" sign append while traversing the soups for @category. do this

```
<ul>
  <% @category.soups.each do |soup| %>
    <li> 
        <%= link_to soup.name , soup %> 
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```